# carousel movement using jquery and css panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the below UI code:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0g2akyrt/19/)

HTML:

```
<div class="cd-panel-1 from-right">
    <header class="cd-panel-header">
        <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
    </header>
    <div class="cd-panel-container">
        <div class="container">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left cd-btn-2" id="1-left-slider"></i>

            <p>
            Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
            </p>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right cd-btn-3" id="1-right-slider"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="cd-panel-2 from-right">
    <header class="cd-panel-header">
        <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
    </header>
    <div class="cd-panel-container">
        <div class="container">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left cd-btn-3" id="2-left-slider"></i>

            <p>
            Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
            </p>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right cd-btn-1" id="2-right-slider"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="cd-panel-3 from-right">
    <header class="cd-panel-header">
        <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
    </header>
    <div class="cd-panel-container">
        <div class="container">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left cd-btn-1" id="3-left-slider"></i>

            <p>
            Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
            </p>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right cd-btn-2" id="3-right-slider"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="cd-btn">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="ic-i">
  </i>
</div>
<div class="cd-btn-2">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="ic-i">
  </i>
</div>
<div class="cd-btn-3">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="ic-i">
  </i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::after,
*::before {
    content: '';
}
a {
    color: #89ba2c;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.cd-main-content {
    text-align: center;
}
.cd-main-content .cd-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #89ba2c;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-main-content .cd-btn:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.cd-main-content .cd-btn-val {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #89ba2c;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-main-content .cd-btn-val:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.cd-panel {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
    transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9;
}
.cd-panel::after {
    /* overlay layer */

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
    transition: visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
    transition: background 0.3s 0s;
}
/*.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::before {
    -webkit-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
    -moz-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
    animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::after {
    -webkit-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
    -moz-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
    animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
}*/
@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-1 {
    0%, 50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-close-1 {
    0%, 50% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
@keyframes cd-close-1 {
    0%, 50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
        -o-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-2 {
    0%, 50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-close-2 {
    0%, 50% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
@keyframes cd-close-2 {
    0%, 50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
        -o-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
.cd-panel-header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 27px;
    width: 3%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: top 1.3s 0s;
    -moz-transition: top 1.3s 0s;
    transition: top 1.3s 0s;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-header,
.from-left .cd-panel-header {
    top: -50px;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-header {
    right: 20px;
}
/*.from-left .cd-panel-header {
    left: 0;
}*/
.is-visible .cd-panel-header {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 1.3s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: top 1.3s 0.3s;
    transition: top 1.3s 0.3s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1471px) {
    .cd-panel-header {
        height: 30px;
    }
}
.cd-panel-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    /* image replacement */

    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.cd-panel-close::before,
.cd-panel-close::after {
     /*close icon created in CSS */
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: 5px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 24px;
    background-color: #000;
    /*this fixes a bug where pseudo elements are slighty off position*/

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cd-panel-close::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cd-panel-close::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/*.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before,
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}*/
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(220deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(220deg);
    transform: rotate(220deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.cd-panel-container {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: #f0a7a7;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.0s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.0s;
    transition-duration: 1.0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.cd-panel-container::scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.cd-panel-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.cd-panel-container::-moz-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.cd-panel-container::-os-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-container {
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.from-left .cd-panel-container {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-container {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel-header a,
.cd-panel-header a:hover {
    color: transparent;
}
/*wobble vertical*/

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-wobble-vertical {
    16.65% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(18px);
        transform: translateY(18px);
    }
    66.6% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    83.25% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
        transform: translateY(1px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes hvr-wobble-vertical {
    16.65% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(18px);
        transform: translateY(18px);
    }
    66.6% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    83.25% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
        transform: translateY(1px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes hvr-wobble-vertical {
    16.65% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(18px);
        transform: translateY(18px);
    }
    66.6% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    83.25% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
        transform: translateY(1px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@keyframes hvr-wobble-vertical {
    16.65% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(18px);
        transform: translateY(18px);
    }
    66.6% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    83.25% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
        transform: translateY(1px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
.hvr-wobble-vertical,
.hvr-wobble-vertical:focus,
.hvr-wobble-vertical:active {
    -o-animation-name: hvr-wobble-vertical;
    -ms-animation-name: hvr-wobble-vertical;
    -moz-animation-name: hvr-wobble-vertical;
    -webkit-animation-name: hvr-wobble-vertical;
    animation-name: hvr-wobble-vertical;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
//Sidepanels

jQuery(function($) {
    //open the lateral panel
    $('body').on('click', '.cd-btn', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel-1').addClass('is-visible');        
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel-1').on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close, #1-right-slider, #1-left-slider')) {
            $('.cd-panel-1').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-panel-1').toggleClass('from-left');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(function($) {
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn-2').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel-2').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel-2').on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close, #2-right-slider, #2-left-slider')) {
            $('.cd-panel-2').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-panel-2').toggleClass('from-left');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});


jQuery(function($) {
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn-3').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel-3').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel-3').on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.cd-panel-3') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close, #3-right-slider, #3-left-slider')) {
            $('.cd-panel-3').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-panel-3').toggleClass('from-left');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

I am trying to achieve the carousel movement using the above code. When I click any of the right or left arrow the next panel comes up and when I close the panel it closes from the left.

The issue is I want them to re-open from right only, currently since they close from the left, when we click the button it opens from left and that spoils the carousel movement.

Is there a way to default the sidepanel to always come from right once they close from the left?

Comment: You have written the above code or you are just modifying some already written code?

Comment: Hi @Viney I have written the above code and using some features from existing examples.